# Question about If $B$ is a $A$-algebra and $N$ is a $B$-module, then can $N$ naturally become a $A$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, algebras

So I think the only point is to show how to build the $A$-module structure on $N.$ We know that $B$ is an $A$-algebra which is also an $A$-module where the $A$-module structure is given by the scalar multiplication. For $N$ we know that $N$ is a $B$-module so by definition it has a group action $b:B\times N\rightarrow N$ where $(b,n)\mapsto bn.$ We also know that the $A$-module structure of $B$ is given by homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B,\ ab=f(a)b$(group action). So we can define the $A$-module structure on $N$ simply inherit the scalar multiplication for $B$ as $A$-module. So for $f:A\rightarrow B$ a homomorphism, we have group action $a\in A, a:A\times N\rightarrow N$ defined by $(a,n)\mapsto f(a)n.$ How we maps $f(a)n$ gives by $N$ as the $B$-module. Can anyone tells me if I think it right? Appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is right.

A more elegant way to do the same construction could be the following: a $A$-algebra $B$ is a ring homomorphism $A\to Z(B)$ (where $Z(B)$ denotes the center of $B$), a $B$-module $N$ is a ring homomophism $B\to \mbox{End}(N)$.
If you compose these two ring homomrphisms you get a ring homomorphism $A\to B\to \mbox{End}(N)$, which is exactly an $A$-module structure on $N$.
Note that this construction in fact coincides with yours, it is just a more elegant way to write what you have already done.

Edit: I've seen that you have tagged the question after "commutative algebra". In this case, note that if you are working only with commutative rings you have $Z(B)=B$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, if you are satisfied with the answer please accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left of the answer. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and mark the question as solved.